# DocuSign Apps` Redirect URIs

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to build a DocuSign integration (connector) to our application and is adding Redirect URIs to Apps for Authorization Code Grant.

Question:

1. What are the limit of Redirect URIs that can be added to both demo & production account respectively?
2. Is there a way to bulk import or mass add Redirect URIs to App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a published limit but I just tried it out on my demo account and it let me add around 30-40 redirect URLs at least (the option isn't greyed out yet but I got tired of clicking). If you find that you hit the limit and would like the ability to add more redirect URIs, create a case with DocuSign Developer Support and we can discuss your use case.

You will need to add all redirect URLs manually, however.